# What means ( value unequal value ) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've seen these snippet in the polyfill shown on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) MDN-documentation:

```
 // Casts the value of the variable to a number.
 // So far I understand it ...
 count = +count;
 // ... and here my understanding ends.
 if (count != count) {
   count = 0;
 }
```

I got no idea about the purpose.

How can something be unequal itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript NaN is the only value that's not equal to itself. So that's a check for NaN.

Answer (score 4):

This is the test when count is `NaN` because only `NaN != NaN`.

Comment: Excelent explanation, but I'm curious about it. It's not better to check it with `isNaN()` method?

Comment: what about `{} != {}`?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I think that just in case that some browser don't have that function.

Comment: @Jai it first convert count to a number so it can't be empty object.

Comment: _because only NaN != NaN_ i asked against it.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude isNaN would return true in some cases it shouldn't. Example, isNan(window) => true

Comment: @DenizEng Well, `window` is indeed _Not a Number_, so I see no problem there.

Comment: I'd not recommend using isNaN function as a means of testing whether a value is not a number. NaN is returned when a mathematical function or parsing to number fails, empty string is not a number either but isNaN("") would return false.

More examples:
https://gist.github.com/kitcambridge/1086528

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: I don't talk about `isNan()` function, I talk about `isNaN()` method, that is more robust than the function. It's not the same this: `isNaN(1)` than this: `1.isNaN()`. So I ask again, it's not better to use `isNaN()` method? The browser compatibility is not an excuse since is implemented in all browsers except Internet Explorer (I guess there are a polyfill in somewhere). See isNaN method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Comment: There is a polyfill in the same web I've attach:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN#Polyfill . So this will be the solution better and semantical than something illogical as `count != count`

Comment: @Jai - `{} != {}` is true because although both objects are empty they are not the *same* object. (Or are you just kidding around?)

Comment: @nnnnnn i know but what i saw in the answer was _because only NaN != NaN_, so i aksed it.

Answer (score 2):

Othere answers has already mentioned why that check is required. But there is another way to assign default value if expected value is a falsy value like `NaN`.

The if condition would not be required if you have this:

```
count = +count || 0; // so if count = NaN which is a falsy value then 0 will be assigned.
```

Comment: Nice shortcut, but I think OP is interested in _why_ such a check exists in the first place.

Comment: @JohnWhite actually i had that in the answer but as that was posted by others so i deleted that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to summarize what's already been said

```
if (count != count) {
```

checks if `count` is `NaN`. According to the [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isnan-number):

> A reliable way for ECMAScript code to test if a value X is a NaN is an expression of the form X !== X. The result will be true if and only if X is a NaN.

(It doesn't matter much in this case, but the polyfill uses `!=` instead of `!==` as required by the standard).

You might want to ask, why not to use `isNaN`? Because `isNaN` doesn't do what its name implies - it doesn't check if a value is a `NaN`, it checks if the value *will be* `NaN` when converted to a Number. For example, `"foo"` is clearly not a `NaN`, still `isNaN("foo")` will be `True`. Conversely, `isNaN([[1]])` is `False`, although `[[1]]` is not a valid number.

How about `count = +count || 0`? It's a valid shortcut, but MDN polyfills try to follow the standard as close as possible. The [spec for `String.repeat`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.repeat) says:

> Let n be ToInteger(count).

where [`ToInteger`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tointeger) is

> Let number be ToNumber(argument).
>
> ...
>
> If number is NaN, return +0.

Note that it doesn't say "call isNaN", it says "if number *is* NaN", and a way to find out is to compare `number` with itself.

Another option is [`Number.isNaN`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.isnan), which, unlike the global `isNaN`, doesn't coerce its argument. `Number.isNaN(x)` will return true if and only if the x is *actually* a NaN

```
Number.isNaN("foo")  => false
Number.isNaN([[11]]) => false
Number.isNaN(0/0)    => true
```

So the cryptic comparison operator `if (count !== count)` can be replaced with `if (Number.isNaN(count))`.