# Check if input is number in JavaScript by comparing with NaN without using isNaN()

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I tried to check if the input entered by a user is a number or not with the code below. It didn't work.

```
var a = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));
if (a !== NaN) {
    console.log("yes");
}
else {
    console.log("no");
}
```

I tried printing the value of a when the input wasn't a number and the output was NaN. But still, this code doesn't work. I know I can use isNaN(), but why doesn't my code work? And is there some other way to check if the input is a number without using isNaN()?

Comment: `NaN` is the only value which is not equal to itself, therefore `a !== a` will be true only if a is a `NaN`. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35455535/989121).

Comment: It works great, thanks

Answer (score 2):

try `isFinite()` method

```
var a = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));
if (isFinite(a)) {
    console.log("yes");
}
else {
    console.log("no");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the typeof operator to test your input value :

```
if(typeof a ==="number"){ 
   console.log(a+" is a number"); 
}
```

Here is the documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/259s7zc1(v=vs.94).aspx

**UPDATE :**

Try also to use this answer of an older post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716488/2862130

Comment: It has been a source of endless frustration to me that `typeof(NaN) === "number"`. It literally stands for "Not a Number"...

Comment: I read the variable a, so before I check types, I have to manually type-cast it to number. In that case, your code won't work.

Comment: I see, check my update, I hope it will help you (see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9716488/2862130)

Answer (score 2):

> Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (== and ===) to determine whether a value is NaN or not, because both NaN == NaN and NaN === NaN evaluate to false. Hence, the necessity of an isNaN function.

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Answer (score 0):

I often use

```
    +a !== +a
```

since `NaN` != `NaN` !!

Answer (score 0):

As georg pointed out, the easiest way is to use if(a === a) since NaN !== NaN